# Where and when will the first images from James Webb be published?

Tags: james-webb-telescope

Hope this question is not out of place here.

So, do you have an exact URL where JWST first pictures will be released, and do we know the exact time that will be happening, or we just assume it will be sometimes tomorrow (12 June) on Nasa website (nasa.gov) ?

Comment: jwst.nasa.gov has a "Countdown: 1st Images" button.  It's actually, July 12, not June.

Comment: Everywhere. They will be published freakin everywhere.

Comment: @Greg Miller NOOOOOOO! I was under the impression that it's going to be tomorrow :(

Comment: I concur with @GregMiller: The target is July 12.

Comment: Technically wasn’t this the release of the first images? https://www.nasa.gov/press-release/nasa-s-webb-reaches-alignment-milestone-optics-working-successfully/